# Why on_delete of Django Rest Framework not work as expected on Image and File Fields?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-orm

When I delete the parent table using Django rest due to on_delete it deletes the child table also (due to foreign key) but the Image and File content of the child table not deleted.
I want to delete those images and Files also..!
How to do that..?

My tables
1:Group
2:Posts
One To Many Relation

I delete the Group table as follows:

```
GroupsModel.objects.filter(id=py_data.get('group_id')).delete()
```

GroupsModel :

```
class GroupsModel(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    group_description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    group_joining_link = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', unique=True)
    user_id = models.ManyToManyField(UserModel, through='UserModelGroupsModel', related_name='u_g')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'groups'
```

GroupPostsModel:

```
class GroupPostsModel(models.Model):
    post_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    post_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='post_images/')
    document = models.FileField(blank=True,null=True, upload_to='post_documents/')
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(GroupsModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'group_posts'
```

I want to delete image and document file also automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an instance is removed referred files are not deleted, since the `ImageField`/`FileField` is only a reference to the files. You can override the `delete` method of your model:

```py
import os

class GroupPostsModel(models.Model):
    post_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    post_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='post_images/')
    document = models.FileField(blank=True,null=True, upload_to='post_documents/')
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(GroupsModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def delete(self):
       if self.image:
          if os.path.isfile(self.image.path):
             os.remove(self.image.path)

       if self.document:
          if os.path.isfile(self.document.path):
             os.remove(self.document.path)
       
       super().delete()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'group_posts'
```

The `delete` method will not be called in the queryset you wrote, you need to delete each instance individually:

```py
for instance in GroupsModel.objects.filter(id=py_data.get('group_id')):
   instance.delete()
```

Comment: Be careful, it wont work for the given exemple, as `delete()` is called on a queryset and not on the model.

Comment: @Blusky Thanks for the note, I have updated my answer to show how to delete multiple instances

Answer (score 1):

`on_delete=models.CASCADE` on a `ForeignKey` is something written and managed on the database schema. It is not Django that delete the child model on delete, but your database (MySQL, Postgres, ...) that automaticaly detect a failure on ForeignKey and perform a Cascade action (like a contraint).

`models.ImageField` and `models.FileField` are (at database level) just a CharField with the location on the file system of your file. The database cannot remove a file, so you cannot delegate this action to the database.

If you want automatic removal of file on Model `.delete()`, you have multiple possible strategy :

- Periodic check that for each file, a model exists (if not, remove the file)
- Overwrite the `.delete()` method of `GroupPostsModel` (but it will only work if you call `.delete()` on an instance of the model, not on a queryset, like on your exemple)
- Add the removal feature on the delete endpoint.